# in which file are the targets defined for android?

Tags: android, compilation, target

Where in the source code of android are the  targets Java Dex Jar etc defined for compilation?Is there any build.xml etc for this puurpose? When I use the command 'make targets' I do not see the list of targets as well for gingerbread.'No rule to make targets' error appears!!How to resolve this as well

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check in default.properties in your project folder. That is the only place i know where android looks for targets. typically it is android-8, android-9 etc..